# How can i repeat assignment value to different types of datas?

Tags: c

I have data list of different data types.

Datas are like this.

data1 : uint8

data2 : int16

data3 : float32
…

And I want to assignment value to datas as below.

```
data1 = 10;
data2 = -40;
data3 = 273.2;
…
```

Because there are many datas, I want to repeat aggignment work more conveniently somewhat like using for loop.

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what you currently do. If I understand correctly your intention, this is not practically possible in C, but without seeing code, this is just a guess.

Comment: @user3121023: No, it is not similar.

Answer (score 0):

To aggregate your data in a struct:

```
struct example {
    uint8 data1;
    int16 data2;
    float32 data3;
} d = { 10, -40, 273.2 };

d = (struct example) {5, 19, 27.1};
```

Comment: thank you for answer. but the assignment is not done only once. i need to assignment several times.

Comment: Added example of repeat assignment